Upload/download files from/to Discord channel based on last write time
I have created a script which does the following:

Compare the last write times between...

local save files for the game Valheim and
remote save files (Valheim) on a discord channel where I exchange the files with others


If local is newer post the files to the channel
if remote is newer, download, i.e. override the existing files

#############
The main function is "sync" which calls either "FileToDiscord" or "FileFromDiscord".
I would appreciate review for:

What is a proper naming convention for function names and variables?
Is the use of the http.client appropriate here? In an earlier version I was creating the multipart body manually
Do you spot any major disregard of common coding practices?
I am a little unsure about the FileToDiscord function:

Should I use encoding for the files before uploading? <<<--- This gives me a proper headache. If I encode them, upload them: then my script on another client would need do decode the file, right? My main concern is that I accidentally "break" the files for...reasons? Like, file header entries, which originate from sending or whatever. I just want to be sure I can use the script and the files will not be corrupted by the upload. Right now, I can use the files in the game after upload -> download with script, but maybe this is just lucky coincidence.



Cheers, and thanks so far
################
$TOKEN = ''
$CHANNEL_ID = ''
$DOWNLOAD_PATH = ''
$local_file_fwl = 'file1.fwl'
$local_file_db = 'file2.db'
$upload = @($local_file_fwl, $local_file_db)
$header = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bot $token"
}

## Download a file from a Discord channel OR get date of last message
function FileFromDiscord {
    param (
        [string]$channelId,
        [string]$messageId,
        [string]$downloadPath,
        [bool]$date,
        $header
    )

    $message = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/$channelId/messages/$messageId" -Headers $header -UserAgent ""
    $message = ConvertFrom-Json $message.Content        

    if ($message) {
        foreach ($attachment in $message.attachments) {
            $url = $attachment.url
            $file_name = $attachment.filename
            if ($date -eq $false) {
                $filePath = Join-Path -Path $DOWNLOAD_PATH -ChildPath $file_name
                Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Headers $header -OutFile $filePath -UserAgent ""
                if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)) {
                    Write-Host "$($file_name) was saved under $($downloadPath)."
                }
                else {
                    Write-Warning "Download didn't work"
                }
            }
            else { 
                return $message.timestamp 
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No file for downloading found"
    }
}

## Upload a file to a discord channel
function FileToDiscord {
    param (
        [string]$channelId,
        [array]$local_file,
        $header
    )

    # old version here https://sourceb.in/T7lfthUtfP
    # links 
    # https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files, 
    # https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4, 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491129/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-with-powershell-invoke-restmethod
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57690968/how-to-post-two-files-at-once-to-an-api-in-windows-forms-c-sharp

    # TODO build file name interator so that as many files a needed can be uploaded
    $fieldName = @('file[0]', 'file[1]')
    $url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/$channelId/messages"
    $fileStream = @()
    $fileName = @()
    $fileContent = @()
    $stringContent = @("I found these save files")
    
    try {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

        $client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
        $content = New-Object System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent

        $stringContent = New-Object System.Net.Http.StringContent($stringContent)
        $content.Add($stringContent, "content")

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $local_file.Length; $i++) {
            $fileStream = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($local_file[$i])
            $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($local_file[$i])
            $fileContent = New-Object System.Net.Http.StreamContent($fileStream)
            $currentFieldName = $fieldName[$i]  
            $content.Add($fileContent, $currentFieldName, $fileName)
        }

        # Write-Host $content
        $client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New-Object System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue('Bot', $token)
        Write-host "Files are being uploaded..."
        $result = $client.PostAsync($url, $content).Result
        $result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
    }
    catch {
        throw $_.Exception.message
    }
}

## Check if local files exist
function check_files {
    param(
        [array]$upload
    )
    foreach ($item in $upload) {
        if ([System.IO.File]::Exists($item)) {
            Write-Host "$item gefunden"
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host "Some files were not found"
            Exit
        }
    }
    return $true
} 


## Get Id of last message
function get_last_message {
    param (
        [string]$channelId,
        $header
    )
    $message_id = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/$channelId/messages" -Headers $header -UserAgent ""
    if ($message_id) {
        $message_id = ConvertFrom-Json $message_id.Content        
        return $message_id[0].id    
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Failed to get message id"
    }
}

## Call the function 
$last_message_id = get_last_message -channelId $CHANNEL_ID -header $header

## Get date of last message and modification date of local file
$remote_date = FileFromDiscord -channelId $CHANNEL_ID -messageId $last_message_id -downloadPath $DOWNLOAD_PATH -date $true -header $header
$remote_date = [datetime]::ParseExact($remote_date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffffffzzz", $null)

## check if local files exist and get date
if (check_files -upload $upload) {
    $local_date = (Get-Item $upload[0]).LastWriteTime
    Write-Host "remote" $remote_date.GetType() $remote_date "local" $local_date.GetType() $local_date
}

## For development
# FileToDiscord -channelId $CHANNEL_ID -local_file $upload -header $header
# Exit

## Compare date of remote and local file and act accordingly (upload / download)
function sync {
    param(
        [string]$remote_date,
        [string]$local_date
    )
    if ($remote_date -gt $local_date) {
        $confirmation = Read-Host "`n Discord Date $remote_date `n "your Date" $local_date `n`n files are being download - proceed?"
        if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
            FileFromDiscord -channelId $CHANNEL_ID -messageId $last_message_id -downloadPath $DOWNLOAD_PATH -date $false -header $header
        }
        else {
            Exit
        }
    }
    elseif ($remote_date -lt $local_date) {
        $confirmation = Read-Host "`n Discord date $remote_date `n "your date" $local_date `n`n files are uploaded - proceed?"
        if ($confirmation -eq 'y') {
            FileToDiscord -channelId $CHANNEL_ID -local_file $upload -header $header
        }
        else {
            Exit
        } 
    }  
    else {
        Write-Host "Remote and local have the same last modified time"
    }
}
## Call the final function
sync -remote_date $remote_date -local_date $local_date

Write-Host "Press any key to continue . . ."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown')

## TODO Build this later
# loading_bar

## TODO check this 
# Portal names are human readable in the original files but not after being uploaded. In the game the names work though


nit: You might consider choosing "all English" oder "alles Deutsch" for the messages and diagnostics. They're all perfectly simple and easy to understand, but it's nonetheless slightly jarring to see the mixture of them. I am especially concerned that some hapless user, not conversant in one of those languages, would use this for weeks and then be surprised by an error message they've never seen before which is in an unfamiliar tongue. Since there's no Answer posted yet, there's still time for edits to the Question.
